# Swift(UI) multiLayer SVG image

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to show a SVG file in my app in which I need to change different path layers.

i.e. look at this map of countries https://raw.githubusercontent.com/benhodgson/markedup-svg-worldmap/master/map.svg -> how do I change the color of Each individual country separately? (i.e. US will have different color than Canada). As of now I was unsuccessful in my exploration.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Mainly svg to swift(ui) converters -> they usually did roughly good job but it was not good enough. And it created thousands of rows of data which was just not manageable. The issue is I'm not even sure what would be the right way to do it... I haven't found any library that would allow working with svg layers.

Comment: Try adding your code, it will help others to help you.

Comment: The issue is I don't have the code to show as I simply have no clue how to do it so I'm here for an advice.